# How to execute function if class instance is passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, callable, callable-object

I currently have a `TestClass` that is callable. The callable executes a function that raises an exception if any attribute is equal to `None`. The purpose of defining it to be callable is so when `TestClass` instance is passed to another function or copied, it will perform a check that all attributes exist prior to being passed, else it will raise an exception.

The line below that exhibits this logic is `UsesTestClass(testClass())`.

Ideally I want to be able to perform the same check without having to "call" the class instance. For example, `UsesTestClass(testClass)`. Is there a magic method or some other way to configure the class to be able to execute a function prior to being passed as an argument?

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def run(self):
        if self.name is None:
            raise Exception("'name' attribute is 'None'")

    def __call__(self):
        self.run()
        return self

def UsesTestClass(testClass):
    print(testClass.name)

testClass = TestClass()
testClass.name = "Hello"
UsesTestClass(testClass())
```

Comment: Have you considered some other ways of ensuring that `name` is always set? For example, you could require it to be passed to your constructor, and then make it a read-only property or one that checks for `None` in its setter. Generally, it's better to make data structures that can't be in an invalid state instead of constantly checking for that invalid state.

Comment: I have thought about passing variables to the constructor. In my use case, attributes inside TestClass gets populated in multiple steps rather than in one go.

Comment: Add a method to the `TestClass` that checks the status of the required attributes and raises an exception if any aren't what they should be. The `UsesTestClass()` can use that as well as methods within the class itself. Doing it via `__call__()` seems a little weird and possible misleading, in my opinion.

Comment: That's definitely an option I've considered but I wanted  to see if it can happen implicitly, which is what I'm asking in my original question.

Comment: First, the "passed to another function or copied" part sounds like you're thinking from a more C++-like perspective, where object copying is extremely common, and where copy/move/etc. operations provide a lot more opportunities for the kinds of hooks you're thinking of. Python doesn't work like that. It may help to read [Ned Batchelder's article about names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Second, even if a hook like what you're looking for existed, it would be called redundantly, over and over, long after the object is already known to be in a valid state, wasting a ton of time.

Comment: If you think about it, what would allow you to *pass* the object to the check function without first calling the check function on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the types library integrated into python you can do this.

```
import types


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        method = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if not method:
            raise Exception("Attribute %s not implemented" % attr)
        if type(method) == types.MethodType:
            self.run()
        return method

    def run(self):
        if self.name is None:
            raise Exception("'name' attribute is 'None'")

    def __call__(self):
        self.run()
        return self


def UsesTestClass(testClass):
    print(testClass.name)


testClass = TestClass()
testClass.name = "Hello"
UsesTestClass(testClass)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well. Though it seems to raise an exception at `raise Exception("Method %s not implemented" % attr)` when `self.name = None`

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that this does validation at the wrong time it's really buggy. For example, [try to actually call a method of the object](https://ideone.com/8buTYf), and you get infinite recursion.